# Unable to save file to disk "No space left on device"

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I've a java program that writes files to a directory on Linux VM. After writing 4.9 million files, it is failing with the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/test/6BA30639CA0A2772AA0217312B3E847E2399E9A25F50F9960D6A670F4F2533EF.blob.lock (No space left on device)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
        at com.xyz.azure.AsyncADLSHashFileUploader.SaveToLocalStore(AsyncADLSHashFileUploader.java:231)
```

My logic is:

```
public String SaveToLocalStore(byte[] bytes, String subfolder) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(bytes);
        byte[] sha256 = md.digest();
        String sha256str = bytesToHex(sha256);

        Path tmpDir = Paths.get(LocalRootDirectory.toString(), subfolder);
        Path tmpFile = Paths.get(tmpDir.toString(), sha256str + ".tmp");
        Path localFile = Paths.get(LocalRootDirectory.toString(), subfolder, sha256str + ".blob");
        String dstFile = getDestFileFromSrcFile(localFile.toString());

        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        tmpDir.toFile().mkdirs();

        //We can make a safe assumption that if the .blob file is present, that means that it has been fully written to
        if (!Files.exists(localFile)) {

        try (
                    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(localFile + ".lock", "rw");
                    FileChannel fc = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
                    FileLock fileLock = fc.tryLock()) {
                //if other thread/process is already handling this file... no point of us doing anything
                if (fileLock != null) {
                    //local file is already there, no need to write it again
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile.toString())) {
                        fos.write(bytes);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        Files.move(tmpFile, localFile, REPLACE_EXISTING);

                        if(statisticsEnabled) {
                            synchronized (StatsLock) {
                                StatsSavedHashes.add(localFile.toString());
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Failed to create local temp file: " + tmpFile + ": " + e, e);
                        //cleanup temp if it exists
                        Files.deleteIfExists(tmpFile);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
                //other thread is handling it already, so just carry one as if(fileLock == null) was at play
                return dstFile;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error while saving local file: " + localFile + ": " + e, e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
          return dstFile;
}
```

I can see that there is more than 80% disk space available.
I've also checked for available inodes on the file system.

I don't know where might be the problem

Can someone please help me with this regard?

Comment: Have you tried emptying the bin - some file systems include the bins, some exclude them.

Comment: What is the file system the files are written to? Like FAT32, NTFS, ext3, etc.

Comment: @Adder, I've ext4 file system. The mount has 1 TB size `/dev/sdd1      ext4     1006G   29G  926G   4% <mount name>`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, The file system has 7.3 million files only. But, from the URL that you provided, it can support 4 billion records per file system.

Comment: Does the error go away only after you delete some files, or does it go away simply by restarting the Java program? (Trying to figure out if the issue is your filesystem or your code.)

Comment: @MaxVollmer, It's happening after writing 4975552 files every time when I run the application.

Comment: This is not a programming problem.  It is an operating system / system administration problem.